# Odoo POS Restaurant Floor - tables duplication issue

Tags: odoo, pos

I'm using Odoo V11 POS for a restaurant. However, when I design tables in main floor, close POS mode and then resume again, I find all tables duplicated. Is there a proper way to establish POS restaurant mode normally? Do I have a Technical issue with POS module?

Please advise as necessary.

B.R,
Mhdbtashi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clean tables from POS screen and after that you can create the tables and floors from the Odoo itself in the Floor Planning section add the floor and tables belongs to that floor,

then login to POS screen and reallocate the table positions and any other attributes like color, size as it easily configured from POS user interface.

Comment: I tried your method but still i got same issue, so i re-install pos module and it worked, thanks.